# MutableStateFlow does not emitting value changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable, mutablestateof

Case is,I'm scanning hardware with NFC and getting texts from it,it has some steps to receive texts.for example:

step 1 - starting scan,
step 2 - scan in progress,
step 3 - scan is almost finished,
step 4 - scan is finished.

Problem is when I send messages while scanning hardware,I receive all of them,checked it with logs and text is appearing in Logcat,but when I'm setting new value to MutableStateFlow inside ViewModel,it only reacts on start scan and finishing scan,I've also used debugger to see if value is changing or not,value of MutableStateFlow object is changing but it's not emitting new value to composable.In composable I'am using collectAsStateWithLifecycle().

this is view model where I receive messages as String

```
 override fun sessionMessage(message: String) {

        if (message.contains("Error")) {
            sessionError = message
        }
        else {
            Timber.tag("TEXTSHOWNVIEMODEL").d("$message")
            textShown.value = message
            Timber.tag("TEXTSHOWNVIEMODEL").d("${textShown.value}")
        }
    }
```

as you can see,I'm logging MutableStateFlow object value , it's changing when I'm setting new value but it does not emits new value to composable.This is my MutableStateFlow object

```
var textShown = MutableStateFlow<String>("Press upon NFC tag to continue")
```

and this is where I should receive info about changes

```
val text = viewModel.textShown.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

this is composable Text where I'm assigning this new value but it's not even receiving above

```
Text(
            text = text.value ?: "",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
```

Comment: It is hard to guess what could be the problem here without seeing the code. Most probably this is because state flows are conflated (meaning you don't consume all items, but only the last one) or that they skip duplicated items (if they duplicate the previous one).

Comment: Provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: you should provide a minimum code for exemple your viewmodel you composable(just what is important) and you repositories that you are using to interacte with NFC if you are using one

Comment: sorry for late response , just added pieces of code into question

Comment: You have to use delegated value using `by` 
`val text by viewModel.textShown.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`
check out [State in composables](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables)

Comment: last comment doesnot helped at all ...